# How to remove beep audio from textBox?

Tags: c#, audio

I am trying to remove the annoying 'beep' audio when the user press 'TAB' key (actually it works as 'ENTER' because I changed its behaviour). 
I have tried the below code, but it did not work!

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated,thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `AcceptsTab` false? Which event are you in? `KeyDown`? There I found `if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }` to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pressing enter, your code will not address the issue, add Enter condition on your code:

```
f (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
```

Comment: OP says he presses Tab, NOT Enter.

Comment: Actually he says "actually it works as 'ENTER' because I changed its behaviour" unless I misunderstood it.